# Ckeditor bundle - configuration require_js

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, bundle

I have a question. I would like to add the `require_js` property to my CKEditor settings. There is a tutorial on how to do it. https://symfony.com/doc/current/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/require-js.html but I don't understand where should put this setting:

```
{
    paths: {
        'ckeditor': '{{ asset("bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor") }}'
    },
    shim: {
        'ckeditor': {
            deps: ['jQuery'],
            exports: 'CKEDITOR'
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put to my CKEditor config `config/packages/fos_ckeditor.yaml`

```
    paths:
        ckeditor: '{{ asset("bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor") }}'
    shim:
        ckeditor:
            deps: [ 'jQuery' ],
            exports: 'CKEDITOR'
```

Also to Symfony form

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('translations', TranslationsType::class, [
                'label' => 'Label',
                'fields' => [
                    'body' => [
                        'label' => 'form.post.body',
                        'field_type' => CKEditorType::class,
                        'config_name' => 'my_nice_cofig',
                        'require_js' => true,
                        'attr' => [
                            'rows' => 7
                        ],
                        'config' => array(
                            json_encode("    paths: {
        'ckeditor': '{{ asset(\"bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor\") }}'
    },
    shim: {
        'ckeditor': {
            deps: ['jQuery'],
            exports: 'CKEDITOR'
        }
    }"))
                    ],
                ],
            ])
```

It's not working anywhere. Because if I put require_js to my Symfony form I can see it in the console.

[image]

Any idea what config they mean in the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

That snippet is intended to be used in a twig template, as hinted by the `{{ asset() }}` helper usage, during [requirejs configuration](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

Let's assume the standard `javascripts` block and that requirejs is installed in `public/scripts`:

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('scripts/require.js') }}"></script>
<script>
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'ckeditor': '{{ asset("bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor") }}'
    },
    shim: {
        'ckeditor': {
            deps: ['jQuery'],
            exports: 'CKEDITOR'
        }
    }
});
</script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

If you are loading the library any other way then use that configuration object in the initialization adjusting the ckeditor path, since the `asset` helper won't be available outside twig. You can also put the configuration in an external file as explained in the requirejs [`data-main`](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) or use Webpack Encore.

You can remove the `'config'` from the form type and the `config/packages/fos_ck_editor.yaml` content as well, since you are loading it already with `'requirejs' => true`.

If you want to use requirejs in *every* instance of CKEditor, then put [the yaml config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/require-js.html#enable-requirejs) in the configuration file instead (and conversely, you can omit `'requirejs' => true` in the types):

```
# app/config/fos_ck_editor.yaml
fos_ck_editor:
    require_js: true
```

Comment: Thank you, finally, I loaded the require.js but it's not working. I can see in console there is an error in jquery.js `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` in this file was generated HTML page, but I don't understand why. When I removed `deps: ['jQuery'],` from configuration, there is no error but require for ckeditor is not working.